# Determining Odd or Even user input

Tags: python

I am trying to determine an input via the modulo operator; however when I run this code I get a `TypeError`

```
    number = input(enter a number)
    if(number%2 == 0):
        print( 'obviously',number, 'is even') #conditional that prints the number and a statment 

    else:
        print( 'obviously', number, 'is odd');
```

My question is: **what is causing the `TypeError`**

Comment: number = `int(input(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `input` returns a string. You can't perform modulo on a string. So you need to make it into an integer.

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
```